# Given a non-singular rational matrix $Q \in \mathbb Q^{n\times n}$, what is $Q(\mathbb Z^{n}) \cap \mathbb Z^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules, free-abelian-group

**Question**: Given a non-singular rational matrix $Q \in \mathbb Q^{n\times n}$, is there any necessary condition such that  $Q(\mathbb Z^{n}) \supseteq \mathbb Z^{n}$.

**My thoughts so far**: When Q is an integer matrix, it's clear that $Q(\mathbb Z^{n}) =  Z^{n}$ if and only if $Q \in GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$. I am not sure if we can say something similar for rational matrices. For example, take  $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
0.5 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \in GL(n, \mathbb{Q})$. This matrix has finite order, the characteristic polynomial has integer coefficients. However, $Q(\mathbb Z^{n}) \nsupseteq \mathbb Z^{n}$.

Any reference/ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can proceed from $Q(\mathbb{Q})$ to $Q(\mathbb{Z})$ by factorizing 1/LCM(denominators of entries of matrix $Q$)...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ two bases of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and put
$L=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}e_i$ and $M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}f_i$.
Then we have $L\supset M$ precisely when the $f_i$ are linear combination with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the $e_i$.

Let's apply this to $M=\mathbb{Z}^n$ with the standard basis and $L=Q(M)$. Then as $e_i$ we can take the columns of $Q$ and to compute back the $f_i$ from the $e_i$ you need the inverse matrix $Q^{-1}$ then the condition is that $Q^{-1}\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$.